# Sending image and background image email with php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to send an email with one image sitting over the top of a background image, I can get it to work if I do this

```
$message .= "<tr><td background='https://path-to-background/image.jpg'><img src=https://path-to-image/" . $file. " ></td></tr>";
```

But the background image repeats

If I inline style it it doesnt work at all like this

```
$message .= "<tr><td><img src=https://path-to-dir/" . $file. "   style='background-image: url('https://path-to-background/image.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;'></td></tr>";
```

I know it may have something to do with " and ' but Ive tried everything and cant get the dam thing to work,

Any help as always is much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the style property to the `<td>` tag.

Example:

```
$message .= "<tr><td background="path to background" style=\"background: url('path to background') no-repeat;\">Content</td></tr>";
```

Bear in mind that how emails are displayed on different devices will vary. I would recommend using a tool such as litmus to help with getting email templates where you need them.

Comment: Thank you works a treat just need to slightly align it just a fraction out...But thanks again

Answer (score 0):

- Please post the entire code, as it may not be only the message body
  thats causing problems.
- Are you using php mail() or another library?
- Did you set your header correctly to show HTML?
- You might want to try your HTML code in the browser to make sure it works, before debugging the email (background image repeats sounds like a html/css error?).
- Most Email programs do not show HTML correctly. Another argument for testing HTML first. You'll most likely need to inline css, there are a bunch of free tools if you google css inliner, that add the styles as inline.